# Integrate Spring SAML with Oauth2 , token for REST API access

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml

Integrate Spring SAML with Oauth2 token for REST API access

With the Spring SAML Extension i am able to configure the SAML Authentication and able to get the Assertion back to SP,
followed the [link](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) ,

now , it is returning to this "/landing", and getting Assertion and Authentication Object in SAMLUserDetailsService and SAMLAuthenticationProvider,UserDetails Object is populated in SAMLUserDetailsService.

```
@Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }
```

Now my question is , how can i generate the Auth token? from this point, there is not much details available
 so far i tried ,
 created custom Filter , which intercept "/landing" and  tried to modify the URL to /oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer&assertion=AssertionToBase64Url([followed](http://meuslivros.github.io/OAuth-2-0-Identity-and-Access-Management-Patterns/OEBPS/ch09s03.html) ),
 but not able to generate token.
My current configuration, Spring security with oauth implementation  and spring saml is also working independently , so now i want use this two features jointly.

my ResourceServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

my AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

can anyone suggest, how to integrate this, so that, authentication done in 
IDP and return to SP after successful assertion(Authorization part is done) from IDP will generate a auth access,refresh token , with that token user  able to access the api. Can anyone provide some sort of solution...

Answer (score 1):

A while back I hit the same challenge, and after figuring it out I have written an article (which cannot be posted here...). Basically, your oAuth authorization-server is a "bridge" that adapts your SAML backend to oAuth, and vise-versa... find it here:

[How-to-integrate-Spring-oAuth-with-Spring-SAML](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598581/How-to-integrate-Spring-oAuth-with-Spring-SAML)

There is also a repo in GitHub with all the sources, as an example:

https://github.com/OhadR/spring-oAuth2-SAML-integration

I know it just links, but again - article is too long and detailed.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you plz explain OAuth2 Configuration, which issues access token , on expiring access token get token from refresh token complete oauth2 flow. in above link there is no Oauth2 configuration..

Comment: did you see the article?? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598581/How-to-integrate-Spring-oAuth-with-Spring-SAML